# Testing spring security oauth2login enabled applications throws IllegalArgumentException: clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have enabled oauth2login as follows.

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChainCatchAll(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/", "/static/**", "/favicon.ico")
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .denyAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .build();
  }
```

Then I have the api secured like this:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, final List<HttpSecurityConfig> configs) {
    return http
            .securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/api/**"))
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
            .build();
  }
```

Then in my `application.yml` i have setup a custom auth provider like:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: ididid
            scope: openid,email,phone,profile
            clientName: MYClient
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: SOMEURI
            usernameAttribute: username
```

Now when I boot up my application everything work as expected. The problems begin when I want to write test for my application.

My test are annotated with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
```

with an autowired `WebTestClient` and executed with:

```
webTestClient.get()
.uri("/api/something")
.exchange()
.expectStatus()
.isOk()
.expectHeader()
.contentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())
.expectBodyList(Map.class)
.hasSize(0);
```

When I try to run the test they all fail since the application context can not be created with the following error message.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.WebFluxSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSecurityWebFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityWebFilterChainCatchAll' defined in class path resource [***]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityWebFilterChainCatchAll' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null
```

I found [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login-webflux) that has very nice examples but still I can not get it working. How I want my test to work I documented for spring mvc in the [following](https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/faking_oauth_sso/) post under the headline

> Bypass authentication entirely using MockMvc

I want my test to never actually never call the oauth2 provider. I only want to create a oauth2user with `webTestClient.mutateWith(mockOAuth2Login().oauth2User(new CustomOidcUser())` that is used to call my controllers.

How can I use `@SpringBootTest` with `mockOAuth2Login().oauth2User` while not calling the actual oauth2 provider and not getting a exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be an instance of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19823 which is addressed in Spring Boot's upcoming 2.3 release - you may be able to see your issue resolved by trying out the latest Spring Boot milestone.

In the meantime, you can provide a `@MockBean` for `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` yourself:

```java
@MockBean
ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
```

If that does not resolve your issue, please consider posting a minimal sample to GitHub.